# Master Calendar won't Display Overlays when Connected to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have created multiple calendars for different departments and use overlays to display everything in a single Master calendar.

For some reason, none of the overlayed dates show up in Outlook when I connect it. Outlook will only show the blank Master calendar.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Correct, Outlook connects to the calendar instance you're connecting to. You'll need to connect to each calendar individually and then you can overlay within Outlook.

HTH

Comment: Pretty crazy that even today, with SharePoint Online, this is still the case.